# Xcode 8.3 crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode8

I've updated my `XCode` to 8.3 (the newest version) and not every time I open it, it crashes after like 30 seconds.

I've clicked `Convert to Current Swift Syntax` but I don't know if that's what caused the probelm.

Do you have this random crashes too? Any idea how to fix it?

Crash Log: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7a9f4bc1a74b53c0160d0f28773582c9

Thank you!

Comment: did you try to reinstall? a.e. uninstall - install

Comment: Do you have any Xcode extensions installed ? Also try checking the Xcode crash log for useful clues...

Comment: @MaximShoustin I've tried to reinstall it, still crashing...

Comment: @PaulR How can I check if I have extensions installed? I've tried to understand the crash log but I couldn't understand anything...

Comment: @FS.O6: well, did you install any Xcode extensions or plug-ins previously ?

Comment: @PaulR Yes, but I can't remember the names of each one of them...

Comment: @FS.O6: well, perhaps it might a good idea might be to uninstall whatever plug-ins/extensions/whatever that you currently have installed, and see if that fixes the crash. If it does then you can re-introduce them one at a time in order to identify the culprit.

Comment: @PaulR How can I uninstall them? Where can I find them?

Comment: @FS.O6: well, if you're using a package manager, like Alcatraz, then you just go to "Package Manager" on the "Window" menu.

Comment: @PaulR I don't have a package manager there. I've reinstalled XCode, maybe that is the probelm?

Comment: @FS.O6: plug-ins don't get deleted when you re-install - take a look at obvious directories, e.g. `~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`.

Comment: OK, there are 2 files there: `Alcatraz.xcplugin` and `SimplePlugin.xcplugin`. Just move them to the trash and empty it?

Comment: @FS.O6: I thought you said that you *weren't* using Alcatraz ??? Anyway, yes, just move everything out of the Plug-ins directory for now. Also clear out the Alcatraz directory if it exists: `rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Alcatraz`.

Comment: @PaulR I said I don't have a Package Manager on Windows menu.

Comment: @PaulR Do you want me to attach the crash log here? Will it help?

Comment: You could post the just relevant parts of the stack trace from the crash log if you like. I assume that removing plug-ins didn't help then ?

Comment: @PaulR No... How can I know what part of the crash log is relevant?

Comment: @PaulR I've edited my question with the crash log

Comment: @FS.O6: if you're not familiar with stack traces and debugging then just post the whole thing - make sure you don't include any sensitive data though.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you! See my answer above :)

Comment: Do you have any foreign language support installed, e.g. Urdu ?

Comment: @PaulR On my Mac? Yes, Hebrew

Comment: @PaulR Just a Hebrew keyboard

Comment: Is Hebrew set as the primary language ?

Comment: @PaulR No, English is the system language, and on the keyboard I have English and Hebrew

Comment: Here is somebody else with the exact same crash, from about two hours ago: https://gist.github.com/RuiAAPeres/a6b4ee7c4b2f370359b34c0de25d36c2

Comment: @PaulR What does it mean?

Comment: It may mean that there is a bug in the latest version which is only affecting some people - I suggest going back to the previous version for now and wait for a fix to be released before upgrading.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks! How can I go back to the previous version?

Comment: Either restore from your backup system (e.g. Time Machine), or just download the previous version from developer.apple.com and install it.

Comment: @PaulR Thank you Paul! I'll do it! Thanks for you help!

Comment: OK - good luck!

Comment: I'm also facing same crash after open Appdelegate.swift, within 20 sec xcode crash.

Comment: [https://developer.apple.com/download/more/](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) Download other xcode verion here

Comment: I'm also getting the same crash. I'm able to get some work done if I clean the build folder (hold option and click Product -> Clean Build Folder) but it eventually comes back. I looked for the directory referenced in the crash log (~/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs) and it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm facing same crash on swift classes but it is working properly with objective c classes

Answer (score 0):

It's working with me by completely uninstalled and reinstall from App Store. Using `AppCleaner` or other cleaner apps.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite Java Home Directories do this problem in my case.

I try uninstall by deleting xcode but this doesn't work. I Uninstall Using AppCleaner then install and everything is ok.